# Google Stops Supporting Physical Web on iOS Chrome - and soon on Android?

Tags: google-chrome, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I just learned today that Google is no longer supporting Physical Web on iOS Chrome. When i did the iOS Chrome upgrade to chrome release 62, physical web on chrome disappeared, and there is no more physical web notifications on chrome.

I checked and learned that according to Google Team - Yes Physical Web on iOS Chrome has been removed and that "Physical Web will soon be no longer supported on Android Chrome.... Only on Android Nearby..."

Has anyone seen any formal announcement from Google? I am sure we all want to know why.

(Stackexchange question? Please let me know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes it seems like it's gone as there were not enough users: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/physical-web-discuss/5hkPwciMdH4

Hopefully Safari starts supporting physical web.